# local persistent volume in a node (still accessible although the pod using it can be rescheduled in another node)

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and quite new to it.

let us say a pod A needs to use some persistent volume in node A (i.e. meaning the container in the pod A will write some data into some path in node A). Then after some time, the pod A dies and a new pod B is scheduled to node B. Then, can pod B somehow remotely access that persistent volume in node A so that it can still work properly?

In other words, can Kubernetes provide some local persistent volume in a particular node that can be used by a pod and can still be accessed although the pod can be rescheduled to another node?

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation on [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) might be informative.  Kubernetes doesn't have any built in way for one node to access content on another node; usually you should avoid node-specific paths and instead use Kubernetes's volume system to provision storage for you, where that generally can be accessed from or relocated to different nodes.

Comment: hey, @David Thanks for your response. it seems Volumes is not what I want as its lifespan is the same as the pod (meaning if pod restarts, then the volume will be lost). it looks like I need to use a persistent volume instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and `Persistent Volume Claims` when an application deployed on Kubernetes needs storage.

PV and PVC are abstractions and can be backed by several different storage systems, with its own properties/capabilities.

### Volumes located off-Node

The most common backing of Kubernetes PV at cloud providers is [AWS Elastic Block Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs) and [Google Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk). These systems are not local volumes on the Kubernetes Nodes, but accessed over the network. From the applications view, it is accessed through the filesystem, like a local volume. This has the advantage that these volumes **are accessible from any Node** within the Availability Zone.

### Volumes located on-Node

However, the cloud providers also offer Local Disks that are physical disks on the Node. Those are much more expensive, you allocate larger volumes but you also get much better disk performance. The typical usage for those are *distributed databases*, e.g. deployed as [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and actively replicate the data between eachother, typically using [Raft Consensus Algorithm](https://raft.github.io/) - this means that they can tolerate to loose an instance (including the disk) and recover from that state, by creating a new instance - that starts to catchup with the data replication.

Comment: Hey @jonas thanks for your response. I would like to learn more on the on-Node volumes as our app cant put data into the cloud provider due to security concern. So if I understand correctly, it looks like NFS persistent volume is the way to go as it uses the local disk in one node and can be read/write by multiple other nodes. However, does it mean I need to somehow set up NFS in one node?